# Rails selecting aliases in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have 2 tables actor and actor2role. The latter is a lookup (junction) table to relate actor, role and dvd. I need to create a query with aliases, so I have this method:

```
def self.remove_duplicate_by_id(id)
    offendingActor = self.find(id).actor # get the actor's name
    ids = self.find_by_sql("SELECT MIN(id) AS minId, MAX(id) AS maxId, actor FROM `dvd_actor` WHERE actor = '#{offendingActor}'")
    rolesForOffender = ids.actor2role # throws error
end
```

The problem is that `ids` is not an ActiveRecord object so I can't use the `actor2role` method (which is a relationship I've established between the 2 tables in Rails and works when you do something like `Actor.first.actor2role`.

so the questions is: Am I doomed to do this manually and then issue another sql query to recreate what the actor2role method would accomplish or is there some way to do this with Rails objects?

I'd really like to do it all natively if possible because I also have to issue these queries:

```
UPDATE dvd_actor2role SET actorid = $d->minId WHERE actorId = $d->maxId");
DELETE FROM dvd_actor2role WHERE actorId = $d->maxId LIMIT 1");
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this which seems to do the trick. If anyone can spot any code that could be optimized, or something inherently wrong (and feels like chiming in) please feel free to comment.

```
actorObject = self.find_by_id(id) # get the object because we need it below for other queries
    offendingActor = actorObject.actor
    ids = self.select("MIN(id) AS minId, MAX(id) AS maxId, id, actor").find_by_actor(offendingActor)
    rolesForOffender = actorObject.actor2role
    rolesForOffender.each do |r|
        # first find out if the relationship already exists or we get a SQL error for the foreign key relationship.
        exists = Actor2role.where("actorId = ? AND roleId = ?", ids.minId, r.roleId)
        if exists.nil?
            Actor2role.update_all("actorId = #{ids.minId}, actorId = #{ids.maxId}")         
        end
    end
    self.destroy(ids.maxId) # delete this guy in actor table
end
```